# Is there a way to display the sort order in telerik mvc grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

The multi sort columns just show descending or ascending sort, but not the sort order.  Is there a way to also display the sort order as a number?

Comment: Are you talking about the sort order when sort by multiple columns is selected?

Comment: Yes.  I'm looking for a way to show 1, 2, 3 for the order that the columns are being sorted.